# I there a way i can share message from one client thread to other client thread in python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have a very big problem and i want help in solving them problem. I have a real server on my desktop and all my class mate can connect to it. But i want a way of recieving data from one client and sharing it to other clients and vise versa with out any other Interface or data modification. Currently if if many clients send message every thing is messed up the data sent to each other becomes like this: "howarecomebackletscome23jf". So message is packed on top of messsage even though clients are typing. What i can do to make sure than every clients messags either while typing is not modified....

Comment: You can leave a message on server and then another client should check if there is some message for him

Comment: There are numerous chat server/client tutorials on the 'net. Do e.g. a Google search for "python chat server tutorial" or similar.

Comment: Thank you i can know see what is missing from my server Thanks Alot